# jQuery ajax fetch data from PHP into a jQuery variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to receive the status of vote using ajax and php and jquery. Following is my code :

```
var VoteStatus= GetStatus() ;
var ID = $('#ID').val();

function GetStatus() {
    var res = '';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {VoteID:ID} ,
        url: "/vote_status.php",
        async: false,       
        success: function(result) { res=result; } 
    });                  

    return res;
}

alert('Vote Status= ' + VoteStatus);
```

In my php file:

```
$VoteID = $_POST['VoteID'];
$Property = $_POST['Property'];



if ( $VoteID == 0 ) 
    echo 'No Vote provided - Property = '. $Property;

exit;
```

The alert box shows: **Vote Status = No Vote Provided**

Please help.

I have posted the VoteID, but the php file doesn't seem to receive it.

Comment: If the alert box says "No vote provided, then your php script should be working well. Check what this line var ID = $('#ID').val();
 returns.

Comment: I did check that , and it shows the correct id

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use AJAX to fetch data and store it in javascript variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570524/how-can-i-use-ajax-to-fetch-data-and-store-it-in-javascript-variables) - and the many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jQuery+ajax+fetch+data+from+PHP+into+a+jQuery+variable

Comment: did you check if ID in JS and PHP is really 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the alert in here and check if its working

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {"VoteID":ID} ,
        url: "/vote_status.php",
        async: false,       
        success: function(result) { 
  alert(result); } 
    });
```

Comment: Dear sir , the alert box shows this : "Vote Status = No Vote Provided - Property = undefined "

Comment: Are you getting the ID correctly execute this line and check if its not zero
alert($('#ID').val());

Comment: yes I am getting and its non zero , i mean am getting the correct value

Comment: Do you provided quotes for VoteID ? "VoteID"

Comment: IF you are using Firefox with firebug..just make this code change in the php file and see if its non-zero  echo $_POST['VoteID'];exit; and look on your console for result

Answer (score 2):

The name of the POST variable needs to be in quotes, as in

```
data: {"VoteID":ID}
```

Comment: data: {"VoteID":ID , "Property":prop} --- the property is shown as undefined in the alert box

Comment: @sqlchild: Please learn what json is. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ; http://php.net/json

Comment: sir, what's the error in my code ? there's nothing but still its not working

Answer (score 2):

Try this and check jquery ajax  [manuals](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",        
    data:"VoteID=" + ID +"&secondparam=" + secondvalue,
    url: "/vote_status.php",
    async: false,       
    success: function(result) { alert(result); } 
});
```

Comment: THis is GET method ..so you need to change the type attribute to "GET"